# my site show error

Tags: c#, ado.net, connection-pooling

my site show this error

you can also check online it visit only 4 to 5 pages then http://www.pakcarid.com/

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: System resource exceeded.

Source Error:

```
Line 267:            OleDbDataAdapter dtt = new OleDbDataAdapter(tot);
Line 268:            DataSet dstt = new DataSet();
Line 269:            dtt.Fill(dstt);
Line 270:
Line 271:            this.totalview.Text = dstt.Tables[0
```

can any one tell my how to solve it

Comment: How about more context like which language / platform you use etc. Or should we guess?

Answer (score 0):

Are you closing your DataAdapters? You need to either explicitly call `dtt.Close()` or use `using` blocks (they're IDisposable):

```
DataSet dstt = new DataSet();
using(OleDbDataAdapter dtt = new OleDbDataAdapter(tot))
{
    dtt.Fill(dstt);
    dtt.Close();
}
```

etc. The Close() is redundant here because the `using` block will call `dtt.Dispose()` but I prefer to leave it in anyway.

Most ADO.NET objects are IDisposable; whereas I doubt some of these matter whether you close and dispose them or not (e.g. Commands) I expect DataAdapters, connections, etc. do.

Comment: OK, sorry that didn't help. Here's the MSDN article on connection pooling in case you haven't seen it: assuming you're using the same connection string for all connections it should pool automatically but suggests you close connections as soon as you're done with them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502.aspx. It might be worth trying to debug into the OleDb library to see exactly what resource it has run out of if you can - I'm not sure if the source is on the Microsoft symbol servers or not.